# Getting source of a UDP packet when received via multicast group client

Tags: c#, udp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine the source IP of a multicast packet in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292063/how-do-i-determine-the-source-ip-of-a-multicast-packet-in-c)

In a C# client I am receiving packets sent to a multicast group , how can I get the ip address of the source which sent this packet to multicast group ?

the byte data arrives fine, so the code works, but I need to find the source ip address..

```
  Byte[] data = client.Receive(ref localEp);
```

The full code snippet looks like this

```
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
        client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        IPEndPoint localEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4446);
        client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);            
        client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        client.Client.Bind(localEp);    
        IPAddress multicastaddress = IPAddress.Parse("230.0.0.1");            
        client.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);
        Console.WriteLine("Listening this will never quit so you will need to ctrl-c it");

        while (true)
        {
            Byte[] data = client.Receive(ref localEp);
            string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine(strData);
        }
    }
```